# Using Git to track Ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, version-control

Other than the database and log files are there any other files that should not be in the repository for security reasons?

The project will mostly be worked on by myself however the code is to be stored on a shared repository which will  be available to a few other users should they want to pull from it. The project is reasonably simple, so i am not too worried about security in my actual code - this is more to protect any test data etc and to build up 'good practice' in this type of project.

Comment: This is a VERY vague question. It entirely depends on what you are programming, who is working on it etc. etc. etc.

Comment: If you rewrite the question with specifics, you'll likely get better responses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A typical `.gitignore` file in a "ruby on rails" context could look something like:

```
config/database.yml  
db/*.sqlite3
log/*.log
log/*.pid
tmp/**/*"
```

But, as pointed out by the article "[rorgitignore : .gitignore files specific for Ruby on Rails](http://rha7dotcom.blogspot.com/2008/08/rorgitignore.html)", you can also use `.gitignore` to add empty directories.

> Because git tracks contents, not files, it doesn't save any empty
>   directories, since there is no content to track.
>
> This means that when you clone your project from a `git` repository, it is
>   missing the `log`, `tmp`, `lib` and other directories.
>
> This small script fixes that, so `git` adds even empty directories

```
for DIR in `find . -type d | sed -re 's/\.\///g' | grep -v '^\.git'`; do
    [ `ls -a $DIR | wc -l` -le 2 ] && \
    echo Creating and git-adding $DIR/.gitignore && \
    touch $DIR/.gitignore && \
    git add -f $DIR/.gitignore
done
```

> this just outputs the commands to add an empty `.gitignore` file to all empty directories in a `git` project and `git add -f`'em to the repo.

---

If you are still focused only on the main .gitignore file, here is a more complete one, from [iCoreTech Research Labs](http://www.icoretech.org/2008/07/24/my-rails-gitignore)

```
config/database.yml
*~
*.cache
*.log
*.pid
tmp/**/*
.DS\_Store
db/cstore/**
doc/api
doc/app
doc/plugins
coverage/*
db/*.sqlite3
*.tmproj
Capfile
```